Office.js Excel - Auto Open Taskpane error when manifest version is updated
We had a Excel Office.js Add-in where we set the OOXML to auto open the add-in.  We distribute the add-in via O365 Central Deployment (Integrated Apps).  works well.
the OOXML that is embedded into the Excel to auto open the add-in, is below:
<we:webextension xmlns:we="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/webextensions/webextension/2010/11" id="[ADD-IN ID PER MANIFEST]">
  <we:reference id="[GUID or AppSource asset ID]" version="[your add-in version]" store="[Pointer to store or catalog]" storeType="[Store or catalog type]"/>
  <we:alternateReferences/>
  <we:properties>
   <we:property name="Office.AutoShowTaskpaneWithDocument" value="true"/>
  </we:properties>
  <we:bindings/>
  <we:snapshot xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships"/>
</we:webextension>

the issue we are having is when we have to update the manifest file, the version number changes.  If we open the document, certain feature fail to load because the OOXML version is older than the current manifest version in O365.
The open way to fix this, is to update the OOXML on every excel file we have.
Is there a better way?
I'm expecting the OOXML add-in version to automatically update when O365 is updated. We have hundered of excel files and will be a pain if we have to update everyone after a manifest file change.  O365, required the version to be updated when it's changed.
